# How to update an array in an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a react project and have an initial state

```
const WalletContext = React.createContext({
  hasExpenses: false,
  wallets: {},
  expenses: [],
  createWallet: () => {},
  addExpense: (data) => {},
});
```

I am trying to add an expense to `wallets`. An expense will be an object in itself and when adding the expense I use the `id` of the wallet to know which wallet to add it to.

Other code has to be updated but what I want is to add an expense to my wallet and update my state. I tried to concat that expense which I have in my `action.payload`. This is an if statement within my reducer.

```
if (action.type === 'ADD') {
    const updatedHasExpenses = state.expenses.length > 0;

    state.wallets[action.payload.walletId].concat(action.payload);

    return {
      ...state,
      hasExpenses: updatedHasExpenses,
    };
  }
```

Problem is that when I try to get this data in one of my other components I have all my wallet ids but each wallet has an empty array associated with it and should not be the case once I add to my wallet with a wallet id an expense.

I am getting the id of the wallet. This I already checked and I am providing to my component the data I have from my context. The issue I believe is coming from my reducer.

My wallets is as follows...

```
{
 'someId': [{'title': 'sometitle', 'category': 'somecategory' }]
}
```

My payload is as follows...

```
{
  id: Math.random().toString(),
  walletId,
  date,
  title,
  category,
  amount,
}
```

Comment: I think you are mutating the data in your reducer. Instead of directly accessing and concatenating, try using `.map` .  if you can provide the structure of `payload` and `wallets` I can think of some logic. 
`

Comment: concat returns a new array but also I can't use map because `wallets is an object` but not an array

Comment: Update your question with structure of both `payload ` and `wallets ` so we don't have to guess the structure.

Comment: My payload is the expense and gets added to my wallets. My wallets is just an object with strings as ids and to each id mapped to an array of expenses

Comment: You are not assigning the result of concat and the merged array is being discarded

Comment: The first section in [the documentation is "Do Not Modify State Directly"](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). `state.wallets[id].concat(...)` does not do anything, so you're clear on that count. But if you want `action.payload` in `state.wallets[id]`, you need to make `state.wallets[id]` a new array made up of the contents of `state.wallets[id]` and `action.payload`.

Comment: I think I get the concept of it but the issue is that I tried to update my code and seems like my data is all messed up I'll update my question to have the results I am getting

Comment: Thanks, a lot of the suggestions were good but not many worked. maybe it was because of my setup but I figured it out. The post did help Heretic Monkey

Answer (score 0):

Try Object.assign instead of concat and add wallets to your return statement:

```
if (action.type === 'ADD') {
const updatedHasExpenses = state.expenses.length > 0;

const wallets = Object.assign(state.wallets[action.payload.walletId], action.payload)

return {
  ...state,
  hasExpenses: updatedHasExpenses,
  walets: Object.assign(state.wallets, wallets)
};
```

}